# Components glitch when using paintComponents()

Tags: java, graphics, jbutton, frame

Im using paintComponents() to keep the JButtons drawn while drawing other things as well. It works but I see it draw one of the buttons once and a while, while its being used, in the top right for a split second. The code im using to draw to the frame is below. Whenever I open a JFileChooser I see a few of the buttons being drawn to that frame, for a bit, as well.

```
public void run() {
        if(job) {
            GameStateManager.swapState(GameStateManager.stateMainMenu);
        } else {
            screen = frame.createVolatileImage(pixel.width,
                    pixel.height);
        }
        while(isRunning) {
            if(job) {
                tick();
            } else {
                render();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(speed);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

public void render() {
    Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();

    frame.paintComponents(g);
    GameStateManager.render(g);

    g = frame.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, frame.getWidth(),
            frame.getHeight(), 0, 0, pixel.width, pixel.height,
            null);
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: `frame.paintComponents(g);` <- NO, NOT, NEVER! In Swing, you DO NOT control the painting process, you make requests to the paint subsystem for updates and then calls your `paintComponent` method.  You've broken the paint chain in I don't know how many different ways.  Never use `g = frame.getGraphics();`, this is not how custom painting is done and it can return `null`

Comment: Swing uses a passive rendering system, which includes optimisation to improve the speed at which paints occur.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Ill look into it and see what I can do. If i dont use frame.paintComponents(g); then they arent even drawn.

Comment: Without a fully runnable example it would be impossible to make further suggests, but generally speaking, the correct way to request and update is to call `repaint`

Comment: is printComponents(g); any better? This gets rid of the graphical problems I was seeing. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Using repaint() is showing worse problems than the other two. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  My **guess** is you're overriding `paint` of `JFrame`, which is generally bad idea, as top level containers aren't double buffered

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved. Ill try my best to improve the drawing process. Thank you for your help, though. @MadProgrammer